# Is dark energy connected to a particle?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Normally, energy is a propery of particles. Both massless an massive particles can have an energy that is defined by

$$E^2=m^2c^4+p^2$$

So both massless particles like photons as massive particles like electrons can have an energy.

Can we assign a particle to dark energy and if so, what would it look like?

[Dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) is associated with the expansion of the universe. It has a negative pressure, contrary to the pressure of normal particles. The density is positive though. Can a negative pressure be consistent with positive momentum? Pressure depends on momentum. But then what has negative momentum? All particles have a momentum in the same direction as their momentum.

Is the energy a property of spacetime? If so, how can empty spacetime have an energy?

Of course, an empty spacetime can't exist in reality. Virtual field fluctuations pervade the empty spacetime. Is dark energy somehow connected to the virtual particle fluctuations? These particles can have all combinations of momentum and energy so also positive energy and negatuve momentum. So it could be that dark energy is somehow connected to virtual particles.

Comment: "positive energy and negatuve momentum" you mean the squared terms in the formula

Answer (score 2):

> Can we assign a particle to dark energy and if so, what would it look like?

Physicists don't yet know whether dark energy is a particle or an innate vacuum energy density, which is another option you discuss later. The simplest version of the former idea - [quintessence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics)) - introduces one as yet undetected particle species, a scalar boson. In that respect, it's more similar to the Higgs boson than other known elementary particles.

> It has a negative pressure, contrary to the pressure of normal particles. The density is positive though.

That's right: it has an [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)) $p=w\rho c^2$ with $w<-\tfrac13$, and possibly even $w<-1$. (For comparison, baryonic matter - and perhaps also dark matter - has $w=0$, and electromagnetic radiation has $w=\tfrac13$.) The latter, stronger inequality would cause the universe to eventually experience a Big Rip. As for how $w<0$ is possible, it's been compared to the behaviour of radiation in some metamaterials, but the exact mechanism may be unclear until the underlying physics is understood in more detail.

> Virtual field fluctuations pervade the empty spacetime. Is dark energy somehow connected to the virtual particle fluctuations?

Not quite. It may be connected to a different quantum-mechanical effect called a zero-point energy. But if it is, [the real mystery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem) is why there's so little dark energy.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see what is dark energy:

> [Dark energy is the name given t](https://earthsky.org/space/definition-what-is-dark-energy/)o the mysterious force that’s causing the rate of expansion of our universe to accelerate over time, rather than to slow down. That’s contrary to what one might expect from a universe that began in a Big Bang. Astronomers in the 20th century learned the universe is expanding. They thought the expansion might continue forever, or eventually – if the universe had enough mass and therefore enough self-gravity – reverse and cause a Big Crunch. Now, in early 21st century cosmology, that idea has evolved. The universe is seen as expanding faster today than billions of years ago.

Dark is used in stead of "unknown", if you read on the link you will see that it is an open field of research.

Now you state:

> So it could be that dark energy is somehow connected to virtual particles.

The main unsolved problem of particle physics is that gravity has not been definitively quantized, it is a research program. Virtual particles belong to quantum field theory, and thus can not be said to exist where general relativity is the known theory and not quantized.

[Here they discuss dark energy](https://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/string-theory-looks-at-dark-energy/) in the content of string theories and vacuum energy ,, which model quantization of gravity, but there is no definite string theory yet .

> Although string theory offers some possibilities for dark matter, it offers less explanation for dark energy. Theoretically, dark energy should be explained by the value of the vacuum energy in particle physics, where particles are continually created and destroyed. These quantum fluctuations grow immensely, leading to infinite values.

> However, when physicists try to use their standard methods to compute the value of the vacuum energy, they get a value that is off from the experimental value of dark energy by $10^{120}!$

> The existence of dark energy (or a positive cosmological constant, depending on how you want to look at it) doesn’t remove the many solutions of string theory relating to different possible physical laws. The number of solutions that include dark energy may be on the order of $10^{500}$. This dark energy reflects a positive energy built into the very fabric of the universe, likely related to the energy of the vacuum itself.

[Here is another reference](https://phys.org/news/2018-10-dark-energy-theory.html) on the status of string theories and dark energy.

So it is as yet not possible to model dark energy at the quantum level.